# Estoy ingresando los valores desde la BD a un combobox en C#, he creado 4 capas(AccesoDatos, Dominio, Entidades y Presentacion), porque da error?

Tags: c#

Capa de acceso a datos
AccesoDatos
Aqui me marca un error que dice que Puestos no se encontro que utilice using Entidades, pero lo coloco
y me genera un nuevo error

```
public List<Puestos>GetPuestos()
      {
          using (var con = GetConexionSQL())
          {
              con.Open();
              using (var command = new SqlCommand())
              {
                  List<Puestos> lista = new List<Puestos>();
                  command.Connection = con;
                  command.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM Puestos";
                  command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                  SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
                  
                  while (reader.Read())
                  {
                      Puestos puesto = new Puestos();
                      puesto.idPuesto = reader.GetInt32(0);
                      puesto.puesto = reader.GetString(1);
                      lista.Add(puesto);
                  }
                  return lista;
              }
          }
          
      }
```

Capa de negocio
Dominio
Aqui tambien me da el mismo error que en la capa de acceso, igualmente coloco using entidades y me marca error.

```
     public List<Puestos>GetPuestos()
     {
         UsuariosDatos puestos = new UsuariosDatos();
         return puestos.GetPuestos();
     }
```

Capa cliente
Presentacion

```
  public void cargarPuestos()
  {
      ModeloUsuario modelUser = new ModeloUsuario();
      this.cmbPuestos.DataSource = modelUser.GetPuestos();
      this.cmbPuestos.DisplayMember = "NombrePuesto";
      this.cmbPuestos.ValueMember = "IdPuesto";
  }
```

Capa entidades
Entidades

```
    public class Puestos
    {
        public string nombrePuesto { get; set; }
        public int idPuesto { get; set; }
    }
```

Las referencias las tengo asi:
1- La capa AccesoDatos le puse de referencia Entidades
2- La capa Dominio le puse de referencia AccesoDatos y Entidades.
3- La capa Presentacion le puse de referencia Dominio y Entidades.

Alguien me podria ayudar para saber en que puedo estar fallando por favor.

Comment: Cual es el error que te da

Comment: El nomnre de tipo o del espacio nombre 'Puesto' no se encontro(falta una directiva using o una referencia de ensamblado?)

Answer (score 0):

El error lo cometes en el Acceso a Datos que usas el campo 'puesto' y en la declaración de la entidad es 'nombrePuesto':

```
   while (reader.Read())
   {
        Puestos puesto = new Puestos();
        puesto.idPuesto = reader.GetInt32(0);

        // (Aquí el error) puesto.puesto = reader.GetString(1);

        puesto.nombrePuesto = reader.GetString(1); // Lo correcto
        lista.Add(puesto);
   }
```

Comment: Si, ese era uno de los errores, ya lo había cambiado, pero aun asi sigue dando error.

Comment: En la entidad Puestos, las propiedades públicas se denominan nombrePuesto e idPuesto, sin embargo el DisplayMember y ValueMember del ComboBox le asignas propiedades: NombrePuesto e IdPuesto

Comment: ¿Qué error sigue dando? Podrías aportar más información.